# Converting from an SQL Array to String[] array throws PSQLException

Tags: java, arrays, psql

I'm trying to convert a SQL array obtained from a ResultSet.getArray() to a String[] array, but I'm getting an exception: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.`

This is how I set the PreparedStatement:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into normalposts (authorid,message,images,timestamp) values(?,?,?,?)");
pst.setString(1, u.getAuthorId());
pst.setString(2, u.getMessage());

// Setting the array
if(u.getImages() != null){

    // converting String[] to SQL Array
    Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", u.getImages());
                                                // ^this returns a String[]
    pst.setArray(3, sqlArray);
    sqlArray.free();
} else {
    pst.setArray(3, null);
}

pst.setObject(4, LocalDateTime.now());
```

This is how I retrieve that array from the database:

```
Array a = rs.getArray("images");

String[] images = (String[])a.getArray(); //this line causes the exception
```

Why did this line `String[] images = (String[])a.getArray();` throw an exception, and how can I fix it?

---

**UPDATE**

I found my error. The exception occurred because I had called conn.close() before I ran this line of code `String[] images = (String[])a.getArray();`

These are the changes I made: 
I put conn.close() in its own public function and called this function *after* running the problematic line, like so:

```
// my PostDAO class
public static void closeConn() throws SQLException {
    conn.close();
}

// another class
public void anotherClassFunction(){
    ...
    String[] images = (String[])a.getArray();
    PostDAO.closeConn();
}
```

Comment: Is `rs` of type `java.sql.PreparedStatement`? If so keep in mind that `Array` doesn't contain a copy of the column values: "By default, an Array object is implemented using an SQL LOCATOR(array) internally, which means that an Array object contains a logical pointer to the data in the SQL ARRAY value rather than containing the ARRAY value's data." - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: rs is the ResultSet obtained from the database in another query. @EmmanuelRosa

Comment: Thank you @EmmanuelRosa , your answer pointed me in the right direction.